# Get exactly the same image sizes horizontally and vertically (Special case)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a special image gallery. All images should have the same size, but some are in portrait format, and some are in landscape format. Example: If the landscape format image is 500px wide and 300px high, the portrait format image should be 300px wide and 500px high. But the layout shouldn't be based on pixel values, and also not on `vw` or `vh`.

In the last hours, I tried to get the correct dimensions with percentage adjustments. But it's always a bit different in different browsers and browser sizes.

What I need: The (flexible) height of `.vertical` should be the width of `.image`. So it should impact the same pixel value.

Is that possible with CSS? Or maybe with jQuery?

Ah, and it's important to keep this `width: calc(50% - 28px);`.

Would be very thankful for help!

```css
.image-gallery {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: darkgrey;
}

.image {
  width: calc(50% - 28px);
  margin: 20px;
}

.vertical {
  width: calc(72.3% - 28px); /* Instead of this, I need here the (flexible) height of  ".image" */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-gallery">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cassandraladru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AnnieRob_FINALS-434.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image vertical">
    <img src="https://cassandraladru.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AnnieRob_SP-43-1616x1080.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want your images to be squeezed or compressed, messing with their aspect ratio, just to make them all the same dimensions (assuming I am understanding your question)?

Comment: All images will have the same ratio. Nothing should be compressed. Imagine you took photos with an analog camera and all photos have the same size, but some are in portrait format, and some are in landscape format – and you arrange them among each other for viewing.

Comment: Thank you @Anna_B. Perhaps this is a matter of terminology. If some are portrait and some are landscape, then they are emphatically not in the same aspect ratio. Portrait are always taller than wide; landscape wider than tall. If some are, say, 16 by 9 (landscape) and the others are 9 by 16 (portrait), then those are inverses of each other, and that's close, but not the same. And it will mean you have to either ruin the landscape images, or ruin the portrait images, if they all have to end up the same height and width.

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe it was hard to understand. Could you please read the first paragraph again? And in general, my example looks how it should be. But it's not "perfect", you can measure it in Photoshop and realize that it doesn't fit exactly.

Comment: Did you check my latest code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code.

```
.image-gallery {
    width: 70vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    background: darkgrey;
}

.image {
  width: calc(50% - 28px);
  margin: 20px;
}

.vertical {
    width: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.vertical img{
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Since all images will have same size, vertical image will have width of image as height.
According to your css, normal image (portrait image) will have (35vw - 28px) width because .image-gallery has 70vw width.
So vertical image will have 35vw-28px as height.
Please try my code and if you have any question, please comment me.

**UPDATE**

Added jQuery code.

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.vertical').height($('.image:not(.vertical)').width());
    }).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, it also shouldn't be based on vw or vh. I forgot to mention that. The container of the gallery will be a flexbox column with a flexible width.

Comment: Then you can use jQuery

Comment: Unfortunately, the images still don't have the same size: https://jsfiddle.net/z16swa4L/

Comment: What you wanted to do was to make height of vertical image as same as width of above image? Your 2 images have different scale ratio slightly, but if you use same pixel (  please try with rotated image), it will become same size.

Comment: Okay, now I think you are right. That's the last thing I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/b37qx1g9/ – But it doesn't update if you change the size of the browser window. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You were absolutely right! Sorry! But how is it possible to update the sizes if the browser size changes? Could you please add the code for this? Then I'll confirm your solution!

Comment: Okay, just moment, you can use resize event handler.

Comment: Please check updated javascript code, it defines resize event handler for window obj. and running it onload by "trigger" function.

Comment: Thank you so much! <3

Comment: – I just realized that it doesn't work in Firefox without resizing the browser window. Is there a way to fix that?